# how to bind the response (data) getting from services call angular 5

Tags: angular5

component.ts file

```
  public htmlData:any;
  ngOnInit() {
    this._htmlServices.getHtml()
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.htmlData = data;
      });
  }
```

Response from serivces callbelow

```
{
    "html": {
        "title": "HTML Questions",
            "questions": [
                {
                    "qno": 1,
                    "q": "What does a doctype do?",
                    "a": [
                        "It specifies which markup standard the page is using. With the information, the browser determines how to render the page according to the page's source code."
                    ]
                }
            ]
    }
}
```

binding in html p tag below but it is not binding

```
<p>{{htmlData.html.title}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without assuming anything here, it's likely that your htmlData is actually a string rather than json.

You might be able to see this by a:

```
console.log(typeof(this.htmlData))
```

just after assignment. So the solution is probably as simple as using

```
this.htmlData = JSON.parse(data)
```